Moving specific excel files from one folder to another based on the name of the file using Python
Context is thus: I'm doing a data science project to investigate some UK national police data.
I have a folder containing ~4500 excel files - see photo below.
I wish to move the ones which have 'street' in their name to a seperate folder but am scratching my head as to what I'm doing wrong. I also would like to know how I can select the data from just 2024, say, to avoid the dataframe taking forever to load.
I have tried an if statement to try and check for the string 'street' and have also tried checking if the end of the file name contains the string as well.
The folder names are:
Folder with the data in is
C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Data Science Projects\Police Dataset\Police Dataset\Stop and Search
Folder I want to move it to
C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Data Science Projects\Police Dataset\Police Dataset\Street
The code runs but the files aren't being moved. I get the following output (x 5000!):
Checking folder: C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Data Science Projects\Police Dataset\Police Dataset\Stop and Search\.ipynb_checkpoints
Searching in directory: C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Data Science Projects\Police Dataset\Police Dataset\Stop and Search\.ipynb_checkpoints
Found file: Stop and search data analysis -checkpoint.ipynb
File does not contain 'street': Stop and search data analysis -checkpoint.ipynb
Checking folder: C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Data Science Projects\Police Dataset\Police Dataset\Stop and Search\2021-03-avon-and-somerset-outcomes.csv
Checking folder: C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Data Science Projects\Police Dataset\Police Dataset\Stop and Search\2021-03-avon-and-somerset-stop-and-search.csv


The folder:

My code:
import os
import shutil

def move_excel_files(master_source_dirr, destination_directory_stop_and_search):
    # Ensure the source directory exists
    if not os.path.exists(master_source_dirr):
        print(f"Source directory does not exist: {master_source_dirr}")
        return
    
    for folder in os.listdir(master_source_dirr):
        folder_path = os.path.join(master_source_dirr, folder)
        print(f"Checking folder: {folder_path}")
        
        if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
                print(f"Searching in directory: {root}")
                
                for file in files:
                    print(f"Found file: {file}")
                    # Checking if the file name contains "street"
                    #if "street.csv" in file:
                    if file.endswith("street.csv"): 
                        print(f"File contains 'street.csv': {file}")
                        source_file = os.path.join(root, file)
                        destination_file = os.path.join(destination_directory_stop_and_search, file)
                        try:
                            print(f"Moving {source_file} to {destination_file}")
                            shutil.move(source_file, destination_file)
                            print(f"Successfully moved: {source_file} to {destination_file}")
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(f"Error moving {source_file}: {e}")
                    else:
                        print(f"File does not contain 'street': {file}")

# Specify the master source directory containing all the files
master_source_dirr = r'C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Data Science Projects\Police Dataset\Police Dataset\Stop and Search'

# Specify the destination directory where all files containing "street" will be moved
destination_directory_stop_and_search = r'C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Data Science Projects\Police Dataset\Police Dataset\Street'

# Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(destination_directory_stop_and_search, exist_ok=True)

# Call the function to move files into the destination folder
move_excel_files(master_source_dirr, destination_directory_stop_and_search)
print("Done")



Apologies, that was unhelpful - the code runs but the files aren't being moved.

I'm not sure what's the point of for folder in os.listdir(master_source_dirr):. As you can see in output, it causes your code to mistake files for directories and os.walk will already check all subdirectories recursively.

Use of pathlib.Path is strongly encouraged.
Here's a simplification of your code that utilises the glob functionality available in pathlib:
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
# if the directory paths are not preceded with tilde, you won't need *expanduser()*
SOURCE_DIR = Path("~/foo").expanduser()
TARGET_DIR = Path("~/bar").expanduser()

if not SOURCE_DIR.exists():
    raise Exception("Source directory does not exist")

TARGET_DIR.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
# non-recursive search for all/any filenames ending with "street.csv"
for file in SOURCE_DIR.glob("*street.csv"):
    shutil.move(file, TARGET_DIR)


Heres my version of the code, I see you have many categories so I made the keywords a parameter too. It

uses glob to get all the files in the src_dir
loop through the keywords
and move the file only if all the keywords matches

import os
import shutil
import glob

def move_if_contain_all_keywords(file_path, dst_dir, keywords):
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword not in file_path:
            return

    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    destination_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_name)
    try:
        print(f"Moving {file_path} to {destination_file}")
        shutil.move(file_path, destination_file)
        print(f"Successfully moved: {file_path} to {destination_file}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error moving {file_path}: {e}")

def move_excel_files(src_dir, dst_dir, keywords):
    os.makedirs(dst_dir, exist_ok=True)
    pattern = os.path.join(src_dir, '**', '*')
    matching_files = glob.glob(pattern, recursive=True)

    for file_path in matching_files:
        move_if_contain_all_keywords(file_path, dst_dir, keywords)


master_source_dirr = r'C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Data Science Projects\Police Dataset\Police Dataset\Stop and Search'
destination_directory_stop_and_search = r'C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Data Science Projects\Police Dataset\Police Dataset\Street'
move_excel_files(master_source_dirr, destination_directory_stop_and_search, ["2024", "street"])
print("Done")

